# How should assgnment (=) instead of comparison (==) questions be handled?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

There are many languages that use the C approach of `=` for assignment and `==` for comparison, and beginning programmers (and even sometimes experienced ones) often make the mistake of writing

```
if (var = value)
```

when they mean

```
if (var == value)
```

This is often the root cause of problems that get posted as Stack Overflow questions.

I'm wondering what the best way to handle these questions is. I just voted to close [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493443/php-sql-query-not-returning-correct-results) as a typographical error, but it felt kind of wrong, since the answer could help others who make the same mistake. On the other hand, the chance that they'll find the question (assuming they even bother to search for it) is infinitessimal -- the wording of the question rarely lets on that this is the source of the problem. It's always some kind of "Why doesn't my program work?" question.

It's such a frequent question, I think they should perhaps be marked as duplicates. But of what? Maybe there should be a canonical, generic, language-agnostic question that they all could get linked to.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, close as a typo

The circumstances surrounding each of them can be so different that closing as a duplicate would be different -- only the answer would be the same. However, it's a good idea to post a link to a good answer that explains the difference as well, so that they can understand in more detail the issue behind it.

Comment: Someone inevitably posts an answer where they show the correction. The problem with finding a "good answer" is what led me to the idea that there should be a canonical one.

Comment: @Barmar: well it depends - are you asking that we create a list of canonical questions for each language? If so, there's already a few, [such as this one for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals).

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of one canonical question for all these similar languages, with a name like `Why doesn't if (a = b) work?`

Comment: Or more generically `Why doesn't if (<var> = <value>) work`.